# Get signal strength of WIFI and Mobile Data

Tags: android, performance, connection, switch-statement, wifi

In my app I need to check the connection speed of both WiFi and Mobile Data and then compare it, then switch to which ever network has the highest speed.

- So how can I get the speed or best signal strength of wifi and mobile
  data?
- how can I switch one off and other on programatically.

Please help me out.
A sample would be helpful.

Comment: Never done that before but maybe this can help you a bit http://mobisocial.stanford.edu/news/2011/03/control-3g-interface-with-your-own-application-on-andriod-phone/ . Rest of job should be done by checking NetworkManager + connection speed tests.
Hope it helps

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Wifi:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
int linkSpeed = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getRssi();
```

In case of mobile it should work:

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager =        (TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
CellInfoGsm cellinfogsm = (CellInfoGsm)telephonyManager.getAllCellInfo().get(0);
CellSignalStrengthGsm cellSignalStrengthGsm = cellinfogsm.getCellSignalStrength();
cellSignalStrengthGsm.getDbm();
```

Then You should compare this signal levels and if WIFI signal is better keep it turn on, but if mobile is better disconnect wifi

Comment: how to programatically switch of wifi??

Comment: Add premission ACCESS_WIFI_STATE, CHANGE_WIFI_STATE
Then you can use the following in your activity class:

wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);

Comment: remeber that signal strength is a negative value

Comment: code for mobile signal strength checking is only applicable for and API level 17 and above.

Comment: @pepe-pa How can we determine that the connection is too low ?(I want to stop download when connection is too low in signal)

Comment: However, if we use getAllCellInfo(), we must checkout location-permission, otherwise, the application will crash on android 6 and above.

Comment: error cash `android.telephony.CellInfoLte cannot be cast to android.telephony.CellInfoGsm` when use 4G

Comment: Remember that the GPS must be ON in order to access the mobile signal strength.