# How to get 3G/wcdma signal strength in android

Tags: android

getGsmSignalStrength returns GSM signal strength. Is it same for both GSM and WCDMA/3G.
If different, how do I get 3G signal strength in android?

Comment: try this 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/18400074/3518278

Comment: Im getting null pointer exception while calling this....    CellInfoGsm cellinfogsm = (CellInfoGsm)telephonyManager.getAllCellInfo().get(0);

Comment: add
<uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
to manifest

Comment: Still im getting null pointer exception

Comment: Did you get this working? I'm facing the same problem