# Check and Advise users about Poor Network Connection in Android App?

Tags: android

Sometimes the app I am developing takes a long time to fetch data from a remote API because the device network is connected but the signal strength is too low, and in this situation my application's delay is annoying to the user.

Is it possible to set minimum rage of signal strength, so that if it goes below that range, I can instead notify the user with a toast message?

Comment: Please don't vote to migrate **application development** questions to superuser just because they touch on network issues.

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18399364/get-signal-strength-of-wifi-and-mobile-data)