# audio live streaming in android

Tags: android, audio-streaming, internet-radio, network-connection

I am doing a radio live streaming application. My application works fine when there is good network . but it stops working when network strength become slow . I am checking network is available or not. If no network i have shown the message. But the problem arise when there is network but strength is down. After such a situatation if network strength came back also it is not working.

Comment: I found another answer that may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18400074/3743371

Comment: Thank you Nick for your quick response. But can we do it using broadcast receiver. otherwise how we know about poor network connection during audio playing.